# How to create a test environnement on the production FTP

Tags: php, deployment, ftp, symfony1, production-environment

I'm currently working on a symfony webapp, which is already on production. To develop and add/delete/modify functionnality of the model, I work on my laptop, using symfony 'dev' environnemment.

I test if everything work fine, then I pray a little and deploy it on the prod server (*with all the risk of data error, like when I add new not null attributes on the model, prod server configuration special stuff, version of php/apache etc.*).

The problem is that I would like to setup a "staging" server, which would be a copy of the production server (same database, same configuration apache/php), so that, if the deployment goes bad, the production user stay untouched and working, only the staging server is down. But my client has only **1 FTP available**.

So, the question is : **can I run 2 symfony project, with different models, on the same FTP ?**

Or is there another way to do what I want to do ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A staging server should really be exactly the same as production. Same versions, same directory structure, etc... a clone. However, you can still get most of the benefits by installing the site into a subdomain (staging.domain.com). Check to see if their host allows subdomains (%99.999 of them do) and install your application there.

Comment: Yup, I can do a subdomain, but a subdomain is only an url, that leads on the same FTP..

Comment: I run many completely separate sites off of the same FTP account.

Comment: Can you explain how you run 2 symfony project on the same ftp ?